# Data from two columns ordered by time, id

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume we have the following two tables, for the sake of simplicity they have the same columns, but in reality their columns will differ.

Table 1:

- t1Id (Primary Key, Int)
- t1Date (Key, Datetime)

Table 2:

- t2Id (Primary Key, Int)
- t2Date (Key, Datetime)

The following condition is an important one:

- Multiple entries can occur on the same date, then the id is the only distinguishable factor.

What I have done so far in the case of a single table (Table 1) is the following:

`SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY t1Date DESC, t1Id DESC`, this has ensured that everywhere in my application I have a similar view on the resultset.

Now onto the **question**, I want to pull data from multiple tables. Let's take a look at the query I'd have:

```
(SELECT t1Id AS id, t1Date AS date FROM table1 ORDER BY t1Date DESC, t1Id DESC)
UNION
(SELECT t2Id AS id, t2Date AS date FROM table2 ORDER BY t2Date DESC, t2Id DESC)
ORDER BY date
```

Let's assume there are 2 entries in each table on the exact same date, inserted in the following order:

1) In Table 1:  (`1000`, `2013-11-23 09:00:00`)

2) In Table 2:  (`3000`, `2013-11-23 09:00:00`)

3) In Table 1:  (`1001`, `2013-11-23 09:00:00`)

4) In Table 2:  (`3001`, `2013-11-23 09:00:00`)

**Is there then any way to retrieve the results in the specific order in which they have been inserted?**

(Disclaimer: I have not used these statements in practice, so there could be some syntax errors. And of course most actions happen on different times, but the tricky part is when multiple actions happen on exactly the same time)

Comment: Are the PK id's of type AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: if you can stored procedure, put the result into a temporary table and than query that one using your order by clause. that should solve you problem

Comment: @KayNelson Yes they are of the type AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: If the table layouts are different, why are you doing a `UNION`?  How different are they?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse As different as I want them to be, I'm doing it because I need to sort on the `date` in the application view. And the presentation will differ based on from which table they originated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL databases don't automatically keep track in what order you inserted the data.

If you want to get the data in the same order you inserted it, you would have to somehow keep track the order of your inserts. There are two ways to do that: use an extra column just for that purpose, or use the "global id" as id column for your tables.

I'll go with approach number 1 here.

So you will add columns to your two tables and they will look like this:

Table 1:

- t1Id (Primary Key, Int)
- t1Date (Key, Datetime)
- t1globalId (Int)

Table 2:

```
* t2Id (Primary Key, Int)
* t2Date (Key, Datetime)
* t2globalId (Int)
```

your query would then be:

```
(SELECT t1Id AS id, t1Date AS date, t1globalId as globalId FROM table1 )
UNION
(SELECT t2Id AS id, t2Date AS date, t2globalId as globalId FROM table2)
ORDER BY globalId
```

Many databases offer a feature called sequence that can be used to generate a sequence of numbers. Mysql doesn't have that feature, but there are several possible ways to generate ascending numbers. The first thing I would try is to do it from the application layer (and details for that would depend on the language you are using in your application). You could also write a trigger that generates a row in a special "sequence table", reads the generated id, then uses that as globalId.

Comment: Is it possible to write that part in a `stored procedure` that triggers upon the insert on the table (such that it does not depend solely on the application layer), and that that procedure essentially retrieves a global unique ID (by means of using another table)?